# Liquibase "modifyDataType" tag always makes the column nullable

Tags: sql, liquibase, alter

When I do-

```xml
<modifyDataType 
    tableName="EMCostUnit" 
    columnName="GUID" 
    newDataType="VARCHAR(50)"/>
```

In liquibase, it always resets the nullable constraints. Is it possible to add some parameter so it didn't remove the constraints, because now after each `modifyDataType`, I need additional `changeSet` to add back not null constraints.

Comment: "*it always resets the constraints*" which constraints are you talking about? Can you show the corresponding `<createTable>` statement?  And which DBMS are you using with Liquibase?

Answer (score 9):

According to the issue you encountered - you must be using MySQL DBMS.

If it is `NOT NULL` constraint you are referring to, it is possible to add it as the part of the `newDataType`-

```xml
<modifyDataType 
    tableName="EMCostUnit" 
    columnName="GUID" 
    newDataType="VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL"/>
```

Generated SQL would be: (checked on MySQL)

```
ALTER TABLE EMCostUnit MODIFY GUID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: This workaround didn't work for me, surprisingly ending up with `VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL` instead. Simply using `<addNotNullConstraint tableName="..." columnName="..." columnDataType="DATETIME(6)" />` did the trick though.

Comment: I thought of trying to pass the `NOT NULL` in `newDataType` and Google it before trying and found this answer. This worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @orikosaki works. However, as per the [documentation of Liquibase](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/modify-data-type.html), `newDataType` field will `Only modifies the data type itself and cannot define constraints`

I recommend adding addNotNullConstraint right after the modifyDataType just to be safe and ensure the not null constraint gets added.

Example (in yaml):

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: your_name
      changes:
        - modifyDataType:
            tableName: EMCostUnit
            columnName: GUID
            newDataType: nvarchar(50)

  - changeSet:
      id: 2
      author: your_name
      changes:
        - addNotNullConstraint:
            tableName: EMCostUnit
            columnName: GUID
            columnDataType: nvarchar(max)
            constraintName: const-name
```

in xml:

```
<changeSet  author="your-name"  id=1>  
    <modifyDataType 
            columnName="GUID"  
            newDataType="nvarchar(50)"
            tableName="EMCostUnit"/>  
</changeSet>
<changeSet author="your-name"  id=2>  
    <addNotNullConstraint
           columnName="GUID"  
           columnDataType="nvarchar(50)"  
           constraintName="const-name"  
           tableName="EMCostUnit"/> 
</changeSet>
```

Note that in addNotNullConstraint, the property columnDataType is required for mssql, mysql, informix, and mariadb.